# How to enable C++17 compiling in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compilation, c++17

I want to use C++17 features.

How can I switch compiling from C++14 to C++17 in Microsoft Visual Studio?

Or is it not available in release versions of VS?

Comment: Which C++17 features? Which version of Visual Studio? If you're asking about C++17 why did you tag your question `c++11` and `c++14`?

Comment: c++17 wasn't available, and I thought that those who are interested in specific versions of C++ knows better how to switch it.
For example I want std::vector.emplace_back() to give back a reference to the newly created element. I know that +1 line, and I get that reference, But I would like to know the answer to my question anyway. VS Community 2015 (14.0.25431.01 Update 3)

Comment: You should probably check here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/

Comment: You can't enable specific language dialects in VS, you get whatever they've implemented. You might have pretty good luck with standard library features voted into C++17 if you're using VS21015, but not so much with language features.

Comment: Check this out: https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-2017-rc/ . VS 2017 rc should probably support new c++17 features

Comment: @preat MSVC 2017 has a "latest" setting, but that is not released yet.

Answer (score 273, accepted):

There's now a drop down (at least since VS 2017.3.5) where you can specifically select C++17. The available options are (under project > Properties > C/C++ > Language > C++ Language Standard)

- ISO C++14 Standard. msvc command line option: `/std:c++14`
- ISO C++17 Standard. msvc command line option: `/std:c++17`

Visual Studio 2022 ([MSVC C++20 and the /std:c++20 Switch - C++ Team Blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/msvc-cpp20-and-the-std-cpp20-switch/)):

- ISO C++20 Standard. msvc command line option: `/std:c++20`

Any Visual Studio:

- The latest draft standard. msvc command line option: `/std:c++latest`

Comment: The syntax `-std:c++14`, `-std:c++17` and `-std:c++latest` also works, e.g. when you prefer to manually enter compiler options (tested with VS2017).

Comment: Is that not clear from the answer already, or do you specifically mean `-` instead of the `/std:` switches I list?

Comment: I see the benefit when coming from `gcc` or `clang`. Then the `-` is less intrusive (however the syntax still differs slightly (`:` instead of `=`)).

Comment: In VS 2019, to get to Project Properties, go to "Solution Explorer", right-clicked on the project title and select Properties. Then follow directions of this post.

Comment: @BabarBaig, that works but the way I described it works just as before. You need to "be" in the relevant project, for example by opening a source code file or selecting the it in the solution explorer.

Comment: `ISO C++20` what version of the Visual Studio?

Comment: @AndreiKrasutski. There is no ISO C++20 yet but some support in /std:c++latest. The C++20 standard is expected next year. I Edited in a comment in my answer.

Comment: What C++ standard is used if there is nothing selected in Visual Studio 2017 > Project Properties > C / C++ > Language > C++ Standard dropdown?  I have 14, 17 and latest in the dropdown, but none is selected, so how do I find what c++ standard is used in a project in that case?

Comment: @pixel It looks as though the default is still C++14 in VS2019: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/cpp-docs/blob/master/docs/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version.md

Answer (score 40):

**MSBuild (Visual Studio project/solution **.vcproj/*.sln*)**:

Add to Additional options in Project Settings: `/std:c++latest` to enable latest features - currently C++17 as of VS2017, VS2015 Update 3.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/06/07/standards-version-switches-in-the-compiler/

`/permissive-` will disable non-standard C++ extensions and will enable standard conformance in VS2017.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/11/16/permissive-switch/

**EDIT (Oct 2018):** The latest VS2017 features are documented here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version

VS2017 supports: `/std:[c++14|c++17|c++latest]` now. These flags can be set via the project's property pages:

> To set this compiler option in the Visual Studio development
>   environment
>
> 1. Open the project's Property Pages dialog box. For details, see Working
>      with Project Properties.
> 2. Select Configuration Properties, C/C++,
>      Language.
> 3. In C++ Language Standard, choose the language standard to
>      support from the dropdown control, then choose OK or Apply to save
>      your changes.

**CMake**:

Visual Studio 2017 (15.7+) supports CMake projects.
CMake makes it possible to enable modern C++ features in various ways. The most basic option is to enable a modern C++ standard by setting [a target's property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD.html) in CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_library (${PROJECT_NAME})
set_property (TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}
  PROPERTY
    # Enable C++17 standard compliance
    CXX_STANDARD 17
)
```

In the case of an interface library:

```
add_library (${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE)
target_compile_features (${PROJECT_NAME}
  INTERFACE
    # Enable C++17 standard compliance
    cxx_std_17
)
```

Comment: I did the dropdown in my VS2017 but still the compiler keep applying C++98 standard, what the heck

Answer (score 12):

**Visual studio 2019 version:**

The drop down menu was moved to:

- Right click on project *(not solution)*
- Properties *(or Alt + Enter)*
- From the left menu select Configuration Properties
- General
- In the middle there is an option called "C++ Language Standard"
- Next to it is the drop down menu
- Here you can select Default, ISO C++ 14, 17 or latest

Comment: Remember to do this for 'All Configurations' and 'All Platforms'. That's from someone who's spent an 2 hour figuring out why it still doesn't work! But thanks for the answer.

Comment: In the vs2019 that Unreal setup, there is no Configuration Settings -> General -> C++ Language Standard.  Can it be added?  There is an nmake -> Additional Options that is set to /std:c++14 ... but changing it to c++17 doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 10):

Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 does not support the C++17 feature you are looking for (`emplace_back()` returning a reference).

[Support For C++11/14/17 Features (Modern C++)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx)

[C++11/14/17 Features In VS 2015 RTM](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/06/19/c111417-features-in-vs-2015-rtm/)

[VS 2015 Update 2’s STL is C++17-so-far Feature Complete](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/01/22/vs-2015-update-2s-stl-is-c17-so-far-feature-complete/)

[Visual Studio 2015 Update 3](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2015-update3-vs)

[STL Fixes In VS 2015 Update 3](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/08/12/stl-fixes-in-vs-2015-update-3/)

Answer (score 6):

If bringing existing Visual Studio 2015 solution into Visual Studio 2017 and you want to build it with c++17 native compiler, you should first Retarget the solution/projects to v141 , THEN the dropdown will appear as described above ( Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Language -> Language Standard)

Answer (score -1):

**VS Code 2020 version**

In `tasks.json` file, (after you build and debug with the `g++-9`)

Add `-std=c++2a` for 2020 features (`c++1z` for 2017 features).
Add `-fconcepts` to use `concept` keyword

```json
"args": [
   "-std=c++2a",
   "-fconcepts",
   "-g",
   "${file}",
   "-o",
   "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
],
```

now compile and you can use the 2020 features.