# Visual Studio Code uses C++98. Change it to newer version?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, version

I just downloaded Visual studio Code and like it so far. I mainly use C++, but I prefer the newer versions.

I just wanted to write a little test program and noticed, that my VS Code uses C++ 98.
[image: VS Code Error message]

Is there a way in which I can tell my compiler or VS Code to use a higher version of c++?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable C++17 compiling in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41308933/how-to-enable-c17-compiling-in-visual-studio)

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio __Code__ is a different product from Microsoft Visual Studio and does not include a compiler or debugger (it is just a multi-language multi-platform IDE).  It uses what ever it can find on your system as such we need to know what compiler you are using.

Comment: That looks like a g++ message. Read the documentation for your compiler.

Comment: @RichardCritten I am using Mingw

Comment: @tobi303 Visual Studio is a IDE and VS Code only an editor. That post doesent help me.

Comment: Yes understood that in the meantime. However, if it is just an editor then it doesnt make sense to make it use some C++ version