# About std::reduce unknown in vs2017?

Tags: c++, std, c++17

I am using vs2017, when using `reduce` function:

```
     auto norm = 1.f / std::reduce(t_, t_ + channels);
```

and the header is:

```
     #include "numeric"
```

I got below error:

```
error   c2039   “reduce”: is not member of std.
```

but as far as I know, reduce function has been added in c++17. What should I do?

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Please read [no pictures of exceptions](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) / [no pictures of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Then use the [edit] link to replace screen shots of text with nicely formatted/indented text within your question.

Comment: Have you included the requisite headers?

Comment: There are the headers: #include "numeric"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `#include <numeric>` instead of `#include "numeric"`
<> is for system includes, "" is for local headers.

Second thing is that VS2017 does not have full support for c++17 and that's the problem I guess. 
Also make sure you have enabled c++17 switch [How to enable C++17 compiling in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41308933/how-to-enable-c17-compiling-in-visual-studio)

Comment: thanks! I guess I didn't get the full support for c++17.I'll try to solve that and compile again.

Comment: Please do not propagate the idea that `<>` is for system headers and `""` for local ones. *Both* are totally implementation defined in the C and C++ standards as to how headers are located.

Comment: @paxdiablo Except `#include <algorithm>` has a fixed meaning under the standard, while `#include "algorithm"` doesn't.