# My C++ Compiler does not compile an "if" "while", and "for" statement with a variable declarations in it

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++17, codeblocks

I'm currently learning C++17 from the book "C++17 from beginner to professional". In the control statements part of the book, I was told that one can declare variables to be used in an if statement inside the if round braces of the if statement i.e something like this

```
if(int a {2}, int b {2}; a<b) {cout << a << endl;}
```

when I tried that using Code::Blocks it told me it was expecting a ')' before the ';' token. However in the book, there was nothing as such.

On VisualStudio it was telling me

> "language feature 'init-statements in if/switch' requires C++ project compiler flag '/std:C++17'**

In particular I was trying to run the code below.

```
char input;
cin >> input;
if (auto lower{ static_cast<char>(std::tolower(input)) }; lower >= 'a' && lower <= 'z') {
 std::cout << "You've entered the letter '" << lower << '\'' << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Does you book actually have `if(int a {2}, int b {2}` in it?  If so throw it out and get one from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: I'm currently using Visual Studio 2019 and the latest version of codeblocks on my machine

Comment: NathanOliver The actual code is if(int a {2}, int b {2}; a<b) {cout << "a is less than b" << endl;}

Comment: Agree with @NathanOliver;  that code is completely flawed.

Comment: Remove the 2nd `int` and it will compile live:  https://godbolt.org/z/YOy5zF    See _"If Statements with Initializer"_  here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if

Comment: Thanks @NathanOliver for repharsing my post. I think it is properly presented now.

Comment: Have you tried what compiler suggests? Add `/std:C++17` to compiler options

Comment: @Amadeus How can I do that?

Comment: @UjiroOduokpe A simple search gives me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41308933/how-to-enable-c17-compiling-in-visual-studio