# adding /std:c++17 to languages gives: Element <LanguageStandard> has an invalid value of /std:c++17

Tags: c++, visual-studio

i added std:c++17 to the language option in

```
Project Options -> C/C++ -> Languages -> C++ language standard
```

and got the error: Element  has an invalid value of /std:c++17
it is the only error and i'm using vs 2017

Comment: I think that field expects just the language standard, not the full compiler flag. So try `c++17` without the `std:` part.

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46759740/856199 According to that answer, you don't need to actually enter anything. You just select the appropriate option.

Comment: @NikosC.Yea thats the answer im so dumb hehe anyways can you post that as an answer and not comment so i can mark it

Comment: Which of the two comments was correct?

Comment: the one where you said dont enter anything select it from the list

Comment: Ah. That's a duplicate then. I marked it as such.