# error: 'string_view' is not a member of 'std'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, c++17

i am new to c++. i compiled my code in visual-studio-code in windows10, with 2 variables of type string and string_view. string variable is fine, but string_view is giving errors.I also enable c++17 extension in configuration.json and edit configuration/ui file in vscode.

Here is my code:=

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string_view>
using namespace std;
int main(){
      string str="hello";
      cout<<str<<endl;
      std::string_view sv=" world";
      auto result=str+sv.data();

      return 0;
}
```

errors are:=

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:7:12: error: 'string_view' is not a member of 'std'
       std::string_view sv=" world";
            ^~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:7:12: note: 'std::string_view' is only available from C++17 onwards
main.cpp:8:23: error: 'sv' was not declared in this scope
       auto result=str+sv.data();
                       ^~
```

Comment: What compiler are you using?  visual studio code is  a text editor. It is not an IDE for compiling and building.

Comment: i am using g++.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I didn't find any bug in your code. I compiled your code [here](https://www.onlinegdb.com/) (Copy your code there and select the language C++17 before compiling) and it is working as expected. Just check the compiler which you are running supports C++17 features. Because std::string_view is only available from C++17 onwards.
To enable C++17 in Visual studio [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41308933/how-to-enable-c17-compiling-in-visual-studio) and in Visual studio code [follow this](https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=How%20to%20install%20C%2B%2B%2017%20in%20%20visual%20studio%20code&&view=detail&mid=BBBE171FE3B0D66D4598BBBE171FE3B0D66D4598&&FORM=VRDGAR) .

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @Abhi38 I have given you the link in the answer above. Kindly look into it. Thanks

Comment: thanks for reply. But, I am using visual-studio-code NOT visual studio17

Comment: @Abhi38: Visual Studio Code is *not* your compiler. How your code gets compiled is governed by your compiler. So that's what you need to focus on enabling which language you're compiling for.

Comment: @Abhi38 I hope you got it now. Thanks

Comment: @Abhi38 Would you correct my answer as right. It would be very useful for others as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

i solved this error by going to ..
project > properties ... select all configurations... >
Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Language > C++ Language Standard > ...select ISO C++ 17 Standard(/std::c++17)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVqXD.png)

Answer (score 2):

I'm using gcc compiler for visual studio code. In C++17, gcc has made some changed, including integrating string_view and string together.
I think that it seem more complicated now,as string will implicitly convert to string_view, in some case.

For more detail:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0254r2.pdf

Answer (score 0):

> By default, VS sets up the project to x86, but when you open
> properties, it loads x64 instead. I think VS should load the same
> settings you are currently using in the IDE, but that's just a
> personal opinion.
>
> Setting C++17 standard for x86 solved to problem for me.
> **This solution worked for me**
> https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1133349/namespace-std-has-no-member-string-view.html