# error: 'std::string_view' has not been declared

Tags: c++, g++

I am trying to compile an example problem from a book.

I got errors when I compiled on my system, so I tried an online compiler and it worked. I updated g++ to version 9 and tried again, but it still won't compile. 
I get the error `'std::string_view' has not been declared`.

```cpp
// Sorting words recursively
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>

using Words = std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::string>>;

// Function prototypes
void swap(Words& words, size_t first, size_t second);
void sort(Words& words);
void sort(Words& words, size_t start, size_t end);
void extract_words(Words& words, std::string_view text, std::string_view separators);
void show_words(const Words& words);
size_t max_word_length(const Words& words);
```

First error occurs in the `extract_words` prototype, and all attempts after that to use the `text` parameter, or any use of `std::string_view`, causes an error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: 'string\_view' is not a member of 'std'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58229919/error-string-view-is-not-a-member-of-std)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As noted in [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view), `std::string_view` is only available in c++17 or newer.

In order to use it, enable it in your compiler. For g++ or clang++, use the switch `-std=c++17`

Answer (score 0):

After a day and a half of compiler upgrades, downgrades, frantically messing with parameter settings, including, excluding files and directories, reading dozens of blogs and following scores of guidance [this was the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58295380/12160107): 
**use the switch `-std=c++17`**
Thanks to [Amadeus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2293156/amadeus)!