# How to initialize C++ derived struct by 'initializer list'?

Tags: c++, struct, initialization

I can't compile this code:

```
struct Base
{
    int A;
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
    int B;
};

int main()
{
    Derived d{ 1, 2 };
    return 0;
}
```

> Error C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'Derived'

How can I initialize this struct as `Derived d.A = 1, d.B = 2`?

I'm using **Visual Studio Professional 2017** Version 15.6.0.

**Answer:**

Upgraded to  Visual Studio Professional 2019(Version 16.3.5), compiling successes with /std:c++17 option.

Comment: What C++ standard are you compiling for? Can you increase it to C++ 17?

Comment: If you are using g++ or clang, add the `-std=c++17` option, if you are using MSVC, use `/std:c++17`

Comment: Almost Duplicate: [How to enable C++17 compiling in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41308933/how-to-enable-c17-compiling-in-visual-studio)

Comment: In Visual Studio Professional 2017, compiling failed with /std:c++17 option. In Visual Studio Professional 2019(Version 16.3.5), compiling successes with /std:c++17 option.

Comment: Aggregate initialization is out then, unfortunately. I think that leaves you with adding constructors.