# namespace std:: does not contain optional

Tags: c++, stdoptional

I am doing the Vulkan Tutorial
https://vulkan-tutorial.com/

```
#define GLFW_INCLUE_VULKAN
#include<GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include<optional>

struct s {
    std::optional<uint32_t> num;//Intellisense Error
};

int main() {
    return 5;
}
```

I started with an empty project and added includes and libraries;
I can compile and run without including std::optional.

When I use std::optional I get c2039 "optional is not a member of std"

I am running Windows 10, and VisualStudio 2019.

What is going on here?

Comment: Are you compiling with C++17 support? This type was added in C++17. Many compilers still default to C++14.

Comment: Which C++ Standard are you using? Because `std::optional` is a C++17 feature. Look at this thread [Change C++ Standard VS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41308933/how-to-enable-c17-compiling-in-visual-studio)

Comment: that fixed it THX.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[std::optional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) requires C++17.

Live on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/VCc_MZ).

you can use `/std:c++17` flag on `MSVC` and `-std=c++17` on `gcc/clang`.

Comment: In Visual Studio need add flag `/std:c++17` to Debug -> Project Properties -> C/C++ -> All options -> Additional Options

Comment: in Xcode:  `TARGETS`->`Build Settings`->`Apple Clang - Language - C++`->`C++ Language Dialect`, change `C++11[+std=c+=11]` to `C++17[-std=c++17]`

Comment: I had the problem after manually adding `-std=gnu++17` in cmake, while the esp-idf build system itself added `-std=gnu++11` later in the command list overwriting my own. I had to hack the esp-idf scripts to disable the latter.