# cuda does not compile member initialization on derived classes?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, cuda, aggregate, list-initialization

the following simple code does not compile in Cuda 11.8, I get `error : too many initializer values`
But that is very standard C++, right? Is there some setting or switch to get this compiled?

The reason why I do not use standard constructors: Because if I add a constructor, I cannot use that struct anymore as a `__constant__` variable

```
struct A {
    int x, y;
};

struct B : public A {
};

int main() {
    B b { 10, 20 };
}
```

Comment: It seems you are compiling your program using C++ 14 Standard specifications. In C++ 14 Standard aggregates may not have base classes. Compile the program using C++ 17 Standard specifications.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are compiling your program using C++ 14 Standard specifications.

In the C++ 14 Standard aggregates may not have base classes.

From the C++ 14 Standard (8.5.1 Aggregates)

> 1 An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided
> constructors (12.1), no private or protected non-static data members
> (Clause 11), **no base classes (Clause 10)**, and no virtual functions
> (10.3).

Switch the compiler to use C++ 17 Standard specifications or higher.

Comment: I already had set the compiler to c++17 in Vistual Studio Project Properties / General Properties / C++ Language Standard. But turns out one has to additionally go to **Cuda C/C++ / Command Line** and enter the Additional Option `--std c++17` there. Only then will cuda use that setting

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63036624/how-to-enable-c17-code-generation-in-vs2019-cuda-project/63057409#63057409