# Enabled CUDA 12 C++20 w/ CMake, but .cu files cannot import ixx modules

Tags: cmake, cuda, c++20

Thanks to this answer, [CUDA 12 C++20 support with CMake not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75010206/cuda-12-c20-support-with-cmake-not-working), I have .cu files building with C++20 using CMake and Visual Studio 2022.

However, when I import a C++ module in a .cu file, it gives an error: "catastrophic error : could not find module file for module"

Are C++20 modules supported in CUDA 12? I cannot find examples anywhere.

It is also possible that I need to modify the CMake configuration, but I'm not sure what needs to be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting the CUDA 12.0 [documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#module-support):

> Modules are not supported in CUDA C++, in either host or device code. Uses of the module, export and import keywords are diagnosed as errors.

Comment: Thank you for finding what I could not!

Comment: @DaleBarnard: It wouldn't kill NVIDIA to provide a decent error message though. :-(