# I don't know why this static_assert() code doesn't work

Tags: c++, static-assert

This is the code:

```
#pragma once

#include <stdint.h>

namespace Detours
{
    static_assert(sizeof(uintptr_t) == sizeof(void *));
}
```

I'm getting this error message:

```
Error (active) E2783 expected a comma (the one-argument version of static_assert is not enabled in this mode)
```

Comment: Do you have some reason to think it should work?

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What outcome do you expect, and what do you observe instead?

Comment: It should work because i'm watching guy from youtube and his code does work but my code isn't working is it maybe because it is 1 year old?

Comment: That's not a technical reason for why you think the code should work. What makes you think the youtube video is correct?

Comment: Error (active) E2783 expected a comma (the one-argument version of static_assert is not enabled in this mode) that is a error that i got

Comment: You need to compile the code in c++17 mode. And add that information to the question.

Comment: `static_assert` requires a second parameter - the error message - before C++17. Apparently, C++17 is not enabled in your compiler. Either figure out how to enable it, or add the error message, as in `static_assert(condition, "Error message here")`

Comment: You probably want to add an error message anyways.

Comment: do you have youtube video or site where i can do that for vs 2019

Comment: Enabling `c++17` is in the project settings. Properties -> C/C++ ->Language-> "C++ Language Standard"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `static_assert` declaration allows the `message` parameter to be omitted since C++17. ([cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert))

You need to enable C++17 in your compiler, or complete the `message` parameter this way:

```
static_assert(sizeof(uintptr_t) == sizeof(void *), "The message you want to show.");
```

---

See also

[How to enable C++17 compiling in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46759740/13433323)

Answer (score 8):

The language feature known (by Microsoft, at least) as "terse static assert" - that is, a `static_assert()` with only one argument - was introduced in the C++17 Standard. Before that, the second argument (a string literal, the error message) is *required*. So, compiling your code with (for example) MSVC and the "/std:C++14" flag, gives this error:

> error C2429: language feature 'terse static assert' requires compiler
> flag '/std:c++17'

And clang-cl gives:

> warning : static_assert with no message is a C++17 extension
> [-Wc++17-extensions]

To fix this, either switch your compiler to conform to the C++17 Standard or, if you don't have that possibility, add the required second argument:

```cpp
    static_assert(sizeof(uintptr_t) == sizeof(void*), "Wrong uintptr_t size!");
```

But note, even with that, there is no guarantee that the assertion will succeed! The `uintptr_t` type is required only to be of sufficient size to correctly accommodate a pointer; it does not *have* to be the exact same size. See: [What is uintptr_t data type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1845482/10871073).