# when I try and use std::filesystem in vs 2019 I get an error

Tags: c++, include, filesystems, visual-studio-2019

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2019, and whenever I type `std::filesystem` there's a red bar under "filesystem", with the messages

> namespace "std" has no member "filesystem"

and

> name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name

when I don't have "::" in front of it and when I do respectively.

I have included filesystem so I don't see why it doesn't work.

I hope I provided enough information, if not just ask in the comments. if you can't help me with that, maybe you could help me find an alternative to `std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator`.

Comment: I can't see your code or a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable C++17 compiling in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41308933/how-to-enable-c17-compiling-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `filesystem` library was added in C++17 and VS2019 starts in C++14 mode by default.

- Open `Project\<project name> Properties`
- Select `Configuration Properties\General`
- To the right, there is a field named `C++ Standard`, select one of these:

  - ISO C++17 Standard (`/std:c++17`)
  - Preview - Features from the latest C++ working draft (`/std:c++latest`)

Then `#include <filesystem>` and you should be good to go.

Comment: I get an error saying 

`Element <LanguageStandard> has an invalid value of "/std:c++latest".`

Comment: @Itay123 Did you change it via the menu as in the answer or in some other way? It has a drop down menu. Don't type the value in manually. What happens if you select  C++17 in the drop down menu instead? Is you source code file named _something_ `.c` or _something_ `.cpp`?

Comment: oh yeah I didn't see the dropdown menu the first time. thanks

Comment: @TedLyngomo yup yup

Comment: @TedLyngomo actually I still have an error saying `Element <LanguageStandard_C> has an invalid value of "/std:c17".`

and one saying `Invalid parameters passed to the Microsoft.Build.CPPTasks.CL task.`

Comment: @Itay123 Did you change the C language standard too (It's below the C++ standard)? If you select both using the menu drop down - it _should_ work. Otherwise, create a new clean project and try selecting the C++ standard there and test to compile. You just have to put `int main() {}` in the program to test if that works.

Comment: didn't work. made a new project like you said and that fixed it. thank you so much!

Comment: of course! I forgot. thanks for reminding me

Comment: For Visual Studio 2017 users: It's `Configuration Properties \ C/C++ \ Language` and then `C++ Language Standard`.