# Structured bindings in foreach loop

Tags: c++, c++17, structured-bindings

Consider fallowing peace of code:

```
using trading_day = std::pair<int, bool>;
using fun_intersection = vector<pair<int, bool>>;
double stock_trading_simulation(const fun_vals& day_value, fun_intersection& trade_days, int base_stock_amount = 1000)
{
    int act_stock_amount = base_stock_amount;
    for(auto trade  : trade_days)
    {
        if (trade.second == BUY)// how to change it to trade.action?
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is to instead of referring to `pair` as `.first` and `.second` I would want to refer to them as .day and .action, is it possible in any practical way to use c++17 or earlier versions?

I tried doing something like this:

```
for(auto[day,action] trade  : trade_days)
```

however it does not compile.

Comment: You already hint at what you need to do: `auto [day, action] : trade_days`. What about this doesn't work for you?

Comment: @user17732522 i tried in in visual studio 2019, however it doesnt work so i was wondering if its about my IDE or just me making a mistake

Comment: `trade` doesn't belong in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by [`user17732522`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17732522/user17732522), you can use `range-based for loops` for this purpose as such:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using trading_day = std::pair<int, bool>;
using fun_intersection = std::vector<std::pair<int, bool>>;

int main()
{
    fun_intersection fi({ {1, true}, {0, true}, {1, false}, {0, false} });
    for (auto& [day, action] : fi)
    {
        if (day == 1 && action == true) std::cout << "Success!" << std::endl;
        else std::cout << "Fail!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

### Output:

```
Success!
Fail!
Fail!
Fail!
```

Comment: it does not work for me in vs enterprise 2019

Comment: i get compiler error:   error C2429: language feature 'structured bindings' requires compiler flag '/std:c++17'

Comment: @MichałTurek You need to set the language version to C++17. I assumed you had done so already, since you are specifically asking for a C++17 solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41308933/how-to-enable-c17-compiling-in-visual-studio