# Boolean function encounters with warning as "not all control paths return a value" or "control reaches end of non-void function"?

Tags: c++, return-type, boolean-expression

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool isPrime(int);

int main()
{
    int n;
    cout<<"Enter range to print Prime Numbers\n";
    cin >> n;
    // 1 to 10 - 2,3,5,7
    for(int i = 2;i<=n;i++){
        if(isPrime(i)){
            cout<<i<<", "; //if it is PN
        }
    }
    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}

bool isPrime(int n) {
    int i;   
    for(i = 2;i<=n/2;i++){  //-n/2
        if(n % i == 0){
            return false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(i > n/2){
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here a `bool` function is used for checking whether an input number is prime or not and returns a value at each conditional statement within it, but still there is an error of not returning a value at all control paths, why???

Comment: You don't need to `break` after a `return` statement. Also, if you reach the `if (i > n/2)` line, aren't you guaranteed that the condition is true?

Comment: I think the compiler did not figure out that i had to be greater than n/2 to exit the for loop however you didn't need to check `if(i > n/2)` just return true;

Comment: And if your final `if` evaluates to false? What are you returning? The error is very clear on the matter. Better yet, why is that an `if` at all?

Answer (score 0):

If control reaches the if statement after the loop, then it is guaranteed that `i > n/2` is `true`. However, the compiler does not know this and it sees that no value is returned if the condition is `false` as there is no else branch and no additional statements. The solution here is to directly return `true` after the loop; there is no need to check a condition that must be true.

A few additional improvements:

- [`using namespace std;` should be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). Instead, you could write using declarations for only the namespace members you actually need.
- You can reduce the range of factors you check in the `isPrime` function by only going up to the square root of the input number.
- Remove the `break` statement after `return false;` since it will never be reached.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using std::cout, std::cin, std::endl;

bool isPrime(int);

int main() {
    int n;
    cout << "Enter range to print Prime Numbers\n";
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        if (isPrime(i)) {
            cout << i << ", ";
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}

bool isPrime(int n) {
    for (int i = 2; i * i <= n; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but it doesn't allow to use of more than one using declarator, this sequence works fine by declaring each using declarator in different lines.

Comment: @Muskanahuja It is allowed starting in C++ 17. What version are you using?

Comment: It is of 17.2.5

Comment: @Enola That seems like your compiler version. If you compile with `-std=c++17` (or newer) for GCC, it should work. For Visual Studio, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41308933/how-to-enable-c17-compiling-in-visual-studio

Comment: @Enola And if that doesn't work, then just use separate `using` statements: `using std::cout; using std::cin; using std::endl;`

Comment: The condition that is always true would be  a perfect candidate for an assertion...

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, already But I don't know what's the matter with VSCODE, I have tried every method to update the C++ version in it, but it doesn't work, instead program doesn't execute.