# Visual Studio 2019 appears to ignore its language level setting for C++

Tags: c++, c++14

I have a C++ project in Visual Studio 2019. Preferences are set to support C++14 (at least that is my understanding).
Here's my preference panel:
[image]
But here's a pic of some of my source with the cursor hovering over the word "`__cplusplus`":
[image]

And yes, I have tried adding the "L" so that my compiler directive refers to "201400L" but that didn't make any difference. How can I get VS to compile C++14?

Comment: Visual Studio projects have different properties for different configurations. You may be only editing one of those configurations and using a different one to compile the code. Make sure to change the two drop boxes in the properties window to "All Configurations" and "All Platforms".

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/46759740/451600  help your situation?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I'm working strictly with the Debug version at the moment, and usually select "All Configurations" when I'm manipulating file properties.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe Thanks but no, I want C++14, not C++17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable [/Zc:__cplusplus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-cplusplus?view=msvc-170).

Comment: Just to be clear however, "How can I get VS to compile C++14?" -- it already is. It's just the macro that's not getting updated.