Variadic arguments vs. upcasting arguments
The overloaded variadic version of a function is supposed to have the lowest priority, when the compiler chooses a template specialization. However, this is not the case when a function argument has to be upcasted to a base class first before it matches a template argument.
See the example below.
class A {};
class B : public A {};
template<class... Args>
void foo(Args&&... argsPack) {
    std::cout << "variadic function called" << std::endl;
}
void foo(A&) {
    std::cout << "non-variadic function called" << std::endl;
}


int main() {
    foo("Hello");
    B b;
    foo(b);
}

The output of this program results in
variadic function called
variadic function called

If I wanted the non-variadic function to be called, I would have to delete the variadic overloaded function entirely. Or alternatively I would have to write a third overloaded function that accepts instances of class B directly:
void foo(B&) {
    std::cout << "non-variadic function called" << std::endl;
}

However, I want to avoid both solutions, because they are not elegant and error prone for my project.
So is there a third solution for this?

You can upcast manually: foo(static_cast<A&>(b));. Template is a better match for B& argument, because it requires no conversions.

All right. I forgot to mention that I have considered this option as well, but it is not an elegant solution either, because static_cast is something that the end-user should not be required to use. It is too error prone imo.

calling foo(A&) requires implicit conversion and calling foo<B&>(Args&&... argsPack) does not. So variadic version wins overload resolution and this is normal/expected behavior. Note that templates are greedy, since they can mach anything without conversion. Please specify C++ standard so best solution could be provided.

I don't exactly know what your end goals is but could it be viable to use something like std::enable_if_t<!std::is_base_of_v<A, Args...>>

@Nifil: I have tried std::enable_if, but I could not get it to work the way I want.

I feel like this is a dupe. Or, rather a common problem. Possible solution can be a specialization, but it's unwieldy. For some use-case a mixture of overload and specialization was offered http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm

Re: "upcast" -- there are no casts in the code in the question. A cast is something you write in your code to tell the compiler to do a conversion. The question is about implicit conversions.

@Pete Becker: The upcast that is supposed to happen is when I call foo(b), in which case an instance of B is upcasted to A. This works automatically, unless I have an overloaded function with variadic arguments.

@Tiramisu -- again, there is no cast in your code, up.., down.., or otherwise. You're asking about an implicit conversion.

And cast is another term for explicit conversion, so automatic cast is an oxymoron.

You might constraint your template.
I add extra overload to simplify the requirement:
void foo() // Simulate empty pack
{
    std::cout << "variadic function called" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T, class... Args>
requires (!std::is_base_of_v<A, std::decay_t<T>> || sizeof...(Args) != 0)
void foo(T&& t, Args&&... argsPack) {
    std::cout << "variadic function called" << std::endl;
}
void foo(A&) {
    std::cout << "non-variadic function called" << std::endl;
}

Demo

Your example does not work with Visual Studio 2022. Are you using a very recent C++ standard? My compiler complains that the line that contains requires is an "unrecognizable template declaration/definition".

@Tiramisu you may need to set the version of C++ your project uses to at least C++20. This should be supported by VS2022 : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46759740/7359094

Wonderful! My standard was from 2014. Now it is working.

I would add condition: requires (!std::is_base_of_v<A, std::decay_t<T>>&& sizeof...(Args)==0) so foo(B{}, B{}); would keep working.

@MarekR: indeed, fixed (missing extra parent or should be || sizeof...(Args)==0 BTW).

You can achieve your goal by making both versions templates with universal references, and only enabling the non-variadic one if the argument derives from A.
Demo : https://godbolt.org/z/jqjvcbKfP
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class A {};
class B : public A {};

template<class... Args>
void foo(Args&&... argsPack) {
    std::cout << "variadic function called" << std::endl;
}

template<class T>
// Enables this version only if the condition is true
std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<A, std::remove_reference_t<T>>::value>
foo(T&& arg)
{
    std::cout << "non-variadic function called" << std::endl;
}


int main() {
    foo("Hello");
    B b;
    foo(b);
}


foo(T& arg) is even possible and more similar to OP's code.

requires (C++20) might replace std::enable_if usage.

Improved version: https://godbolt.org/z/4fhnhGjf6
